# PHP Class Database Erorr

Tags: php, class

I am trying to create a simple photo gallery on my localhost using XAMPP.

On my includes folder I have three files:

```
-config.php (constants of database info)
-database.php (Which contains my database classes)
-functions.php (Which contains all my functions)
```

Here's my CONFIG file:

```
    <?php

//Database Constants
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost"); 
defined('DB_USER') ? null :  define("DB_USER", "root");
defined('DB_PASS') ? null :  define("DB_PASS", "");
defined('DB_NAME') ? null : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");

?>
```

Here's my DATABASE file:

```
    <?php
require_once("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase {

    private $connection;

  function __construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
  }

    public function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        if (!$this->connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        } else {
            $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);
            if (!$db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }

    public function close_connection() {
        if(isset($this->connection)) {
            mysql_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }

    public function mysql_prep( $value ) {
        $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
        $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ); // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
        if( $new_enough_php ) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
            // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
            if( $magic_quotes_active ) { $value = stripslashes( $value ); }
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
        } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
            // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
            if( !$magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }
            // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
        }
        return $value;
    }

    private function confirm_query($result) {
        if (!$result) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
    }

}

$database = new MySQLDatabase();
$db =& $database;

?>
```

When I tried to test if my database is working  using:

```
    <?php
require_once("../includes/database.php");


if(isset($database)){
    echo "Database is working?";
}else{
    echo "Database not working!";
}



?>
```

on my index.php file which is on a different folder for public access, I got the following errors:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 13
Database connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

I tried rechecking my database information but I am confident that I got them correctly. Any idea what's causing this? Thanks in advance for those who can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local hosted mysql using PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520612/cant-connect-to-local-hosted-mysql-using-php-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not trust relative path when including files. Always use `__DIR__` when you want to refer current directory.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/path/to/you/file.php');
```

Why?

According to [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the
>   include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own
>   directory and the current working directory before failing. The
>   include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this
>   is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.
>
> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter
>   or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the
>   current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be
>   ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the
>   parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

If you don't define a path e.g. `require_once("config.php");`, PHP will get the file from `include_path` list.

Here is a XMAPP default include path

```
.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR
```

Unfortunately, `PEAR` (`pear`) directory have a file `Config.php`, thus PHP include this file instead of fallback this path and read your `config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

checking defined or not is done by defined() but not by comparing it to null
`defined('DBSERVER') or define('DBSERVER', 'localhost')` should help

Comment: I tried to remove the comparation part of the code however still getting the same error.